# Angular material: manually display a tooltip

Tags: angularjs, tooltip, angularjs-material

I'd like to display tooltips programmatically, but can't find a way to.

Example of use: on page load display a given tooltip for few seconds, then hide it.

I could use md-visible attribute linked to a vm.isTooltipVisible attribute. However, I noticed that if there are multiple tooltips declared this way:

```
<tooltip md-visible="vm.isTooltipVisible">Bla bla </tooltip>
<tooltip md-visible="vm.isTooltipVisible">Hi Jack</tooltip>
```

Then if any of those is hovered, all are displayed at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by declaring an array in my controller, so:

```
this.isTooltipVisible = [];
```

Then in your html you could use:

```
<md-tooltip md-visible="vm.isTooltipVisible[0]">Bla bla </md-tooltip>

<md-tooltip md-visible="vm.isTooltipVisible[1]">Hi Jack</md-tooltip>
```

I don't know if this is 'clean', but it's working for me.
I hope that this helps you (even though this question is already 2 months old)